# Macro for LibreOffice to sum underlined data

Tags: excel, vba, libreoffice

I am trying to adapt [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1339-excel-sum-count-bold-cells.html) excel macro to Libreoffice, which will be used to sum the data in cells marked as underlined.

```
Option VBASupport 1
Option Compatible

Function SumUnderline(optional WorkRng As Range)
'Update 20220516

Dim Rng As Range
Dim xSum As Double
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    If Rng.Font.Underline Then
        xSum = xSum + Rng.Value
    End If
Next
SumUnderline = xSum

End Function
```

When executed I am getting error **Data type mismatch**.

Please, help to fix it.

Having working macro which will be both compatible with Excel and LibreOffice.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv4qi.png)

Comment: It is usually better to understand the existing macro and then write a new one in the other language. What is common is completing the task.

Comment: Firstly, the cycle should not be over the range, but over the cells of the range - `For Each Rng In WorkRng.Cells`. Secondly, the sum condition must be specified explicitly as a comparison with a constant, otherwise cells with "none underline" **-4142** will be counted (see [**XlUnderlineStyle enumeration (Excel)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlunderlinestyle))

Answer (score 0):

I am not in LibreOffice but as to the underlying VBA macro the reason is that Rng.Font.Underline returns a Long or a Null value depending on the range's content is underlined or not. This is type mismatch. You need a Boolean return.

Comment: @Black_cat No, the type mismatch error occurs earlier, before the macro gets to .Font.Underline. The default property for Range is Value, an array of strings and numbers of type Variant. Therefore, trying to iterate over the elements of type Variant using a variable of type Range causes an error.

Comment: @Black_cat [The **default** member of Range forwards calls without parameters to the **Value** property and calls with parameters to the Item member. Accordingly, someRange = someOtherRange is equivalent to someRange.Value = someOtherRange.Value, someRange(1) to someRange.Item(1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object))